# Why deadline doesn't work with GAE urlfetch?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urlfetch

If I use the following code:

```
result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url_get_devices, 
                        payload='',
                        method=urlfetch.POST,
                        headers=headers,
                        deadline=10
                        )
```

then I am getting error:

> File "D:\Work_GAE\test.py", line 27, in get
>       deadline=10 TypeError: fetch() got an unexpected keyword argument
>   'deadline'

But if I remove `deadline` argument, then it works well.
What is wrong here?

Comment: The documentation says it's supported. Maybe try updating your GAE to the latest version? The revision history suggests it's been around since 1.2.2 (2009): http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/revision_history.html

Comment: @Thomas that should be the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using a *very* old version of the App Engine SDK. You should update to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks. Strange that RU version of GAE download page contains that old version.

Comment: @LA_ Could you file a bug to that effect? It should be up to date.

Comment: could you please provide me with the link where it should be filed?